# Point a subdomain to my application

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, cname

So the basic idea is the same as what tumblr and a few other applications have used. Through CNAME (or what ever the better alternative would be) point a subdomain of a clients domain name to their application login.

**eg**

1. Clients domain name is client.com.
2. There application login is client.myapp.com.
3. Point login.client.com at client.myapp.com.

What would the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did CNAME not work or something? Sounds like the right tool to me…

Comment: When I CNAME'ed the clients domain name to their application login it spat an error at me. I was thinking it was the right one, too!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you cname only "login" to client.myapp.com. If you add "login.client.com", it probably won't work.